# Range of function $y=\frac{e^\frac{x^3}{3}}{x^3}$

Tags: functions

i am finding range of this function

$$y=\frac{e^\frac{x^3}{3}}{x^3}$$

As a first step i tried find inverse function, but i cannot find it.
Please can you help me with it?

Comment: Is there a reason the $x$- and $y$-coordinates seem swapped?  This looks like $x=f(y)$ which is usually the opposite of standard notation.

Comment: sorry it was misstake

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527569/express-y-from-lnx3-lny-y/1527606#1527606

Comment: OK, final question before attempting an answer: In what context is the question asked?  Algebra, Calculus, or otherwise?  The best method of solving may depend on the answer.

Comment: i have a function and i need find Domain, Range, interval where it is continues, extrems, convexity, concavity...

Comment: Finding the "inverse function" is much harder than finding the range of the function.

Comment: Why would you look for an inverse function when all you need to calculate is the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the other question related to this function:

$$-\frac{1}{3y} = ue^{u}$$ where $u=-x^3/3.$ The range of $ue^u$ is well-known when $u$ is real. We have to exclude $u=0$, since the original function is undefined when $x=0$.

Now $x\to -x^3/3$ is invertible on the real line, so you just need to find the range of $ue^u$, exclude $u=0$, invert, negate, and divide by $3$.

$ue^u$ has range equal to $(-1,+\infty)$. Applying that transformation, inverting we get $(-\infty,-1)\cup (0,+\infty)$, negating, we get $(-\infty,0)\cup (1,+\infty)$, and dividing by $3$ we get:

$$(-\infty,0)\cup (1/3,+\infty)$$